# Python 2.7 Remove white space from a string by str.replace not working

Tags: python-2.7, whitespace

I wanna remove white space from a string, but str.replace not working. Pls help

```
1
s = "asd dsa asd "
string.replace(s, 'est', '')

NameError: name 'string' is not defined


2
s = "asd asd dsa "
str.replace(s, " ", "")
print s
Output: asd asd dsa 

3
s = "asd asd dsa "
s.replace(" ", "")
print s
Output: asd asd dsa
```

Comment: It returns the value. use `s=s.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: It's working, thx